# How to load a YouTube video (within app) by clicking on a UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, youtube

I am implementing a UITableView containing a list of YouTube videos. Can anyone advise me how I can trigger a YouTube video load within an app after the user clicks on a UIButton (exist in each cell)?

I searched the net but only found implementations involving UIWebViews. Note that I specifically do not want to add a UIWebView to my table view but instead what the trigger point to be from a button or image in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953) to play the videos.

You can easily set this up to either play fullscreen, or to play in a view embedded in your app's UI.  See Apple's [Multimedia Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingVideo/UsingVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH3-SW1) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly: Tie the button in your cell class to an action on your controller class, and pass the button itself when clicking via the `buttonClicked:(id)sender` form. Use the button's `superview` and then either a `viewWithTag:` call, or casting and an `@property` on the cell, to get a reference to a variable or UI element within the cell the button came from which will tell you the URL to load (could just be an index stored in a hidden `UILabel` for example, which you then look up in the data store backing your `UITableView`). Then call `MPMoviePlayerViewController` with that URL.